# How to match subdomain with gorilla mux

Tags: regex, go, gorilla

I need to build a route which matches two subdomains(prefix.api.example.com and prefix.api.sandbox.example.com) using gorilla [mux](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Host) router. So far I have the regex below but the router returns 404 on requests. Any idea why is that?

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
route :=  router.Host(`prefix.api{_:(^$|^\.sandbox$)}.example.com`)
```

More code

```
package main

import(
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

type handler struct{}

func (_ handler)ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    w.WriteHeader(200)

}
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    route :=  router.Host(`prefix.api{_:(^$|^\.sandbox$)}.example.com`)
    route.Handler(handler{})
    http.Handle("/", router)
      panic(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}
```

Request:

```
$ curl prefix.api.sandbox.example.com/any -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to prefix.api.sandbox.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /some HTTP/1.1
> Host: prefix.api.sandbox.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 22:08:21 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host prefix.api.sandbox.example.com left intact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` and `$` metacharacters for matching beginning and end of lines should be removed, the parens can be as well.

```
route := router.Host(`prefix.api{_:|\.sandbox}.example.com`)`
```

My hosts file:

```
○ grep prefix /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   prefix.api.example.com
127.0.0.1   prefix.api.sandbox.example.com
127.0.0.1   prefix.api.xsandbox.example.com
```

Gives me the following:

```
○ curl prefix.api.example.com:8000
hello world%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
○ curl prefix.api.sandbox.example.com:8000
hello world%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
○ curl prefix.api.xsandbox.example.com:8000
404 page not found
```

**Updated:**

Here are the regexes generated by the two different `.Host()`'s:

```
route :=  router.Host(`prefix.api{_:(^$|^\.sandbox$)}.example.com`)
```

regexp: `^prefix\.api(?P<v0>(^$|^\.sandbox$))\.example\.com$`

```
route := router.Host(`prefix.api{_:|\.sandbox}.example.com`)
```

regexp: `^prefix\.api(?P<v0>|\.sandbox)\.example\.com$`

- Example tests for both regexes can be played with
  [here](https://play.golang.org/p/VPnxnHziTC) at play.golang

Comment: I think that way it matches more routes than it should, isn't it ? https://play.golang.org/p/uvxjxrfDrE

Comment: If that were the case, shouldn't `prefix.api.xsandbox.example.com` have returned `hello world`?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat updated with the generated host regexes.

Comment: I don't quite understand... is the actual/final regex different than what you type in the route ? Does gorilla mux add its own flavour on top of the std regex? The question is not only what regex is required but also how it works  (i.e. why my regex doesn't work)

Comment: concerning the previous comment  ``prefix.api.xsandbox.example.com`` shouldn't match any route because I've defined only ``prefix.api.sandbox.example.com`` and ``prefix.api.example.com``.  To match ``prefix.api.xsandbox.example.com`` I think there should have been a wildcard before "sandbox" which is not the case.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat - Did you look at my example, or try running it? `xsandbox` *does not* match. If you look at my updated answer, you can see for yourself exactly how the regex is constructed by mux. This should be more than enough to sort out why yours is failing.

Comment: How do you know that's how mux constructs the regex? Could you point me to the documentation(if any ) or source code?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat because I added debug to the `mux` code and checked... https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/regexp.go#L113